# How to cURL Watson's Personality Insights from Windows?

Tags: powershell, curl

The Personality Insights tutorial says to use the following cURL command:

```
curl -X POST --user {username}:{password} \
--header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--data-binary "@{path_to_file}profile.json" \
"https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/personality-insights/api/v3/profile?version=2016-10-20&consumption_preferences=true&raw_scores=true"
```

Which I have translated as:

```
curl -X POST --user myun:mypw \
--header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--data-binary "@C:\mypath\profile.json" \
"https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/personality-insights/api/v3/profile?version=2016-10-20&consumption_preferences=true&raw_scores=true"
```

I downloaded and installed cURL, but I keep getting these horrendous errors in PowerShell:

```
At line:2 char:3
+ --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
+   ~
Missing expression after unary operator '--'.
At line:2 char:3
+ --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
+   ~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'header' in expression or statement.
At line:3 char:3
+ --header "Accept: text/csv" \
+   ~
Missing expression after unary operator '--'.
At line:3 char:3
+ --header "Accept: text/csv" \
+   ~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'header' in expression or statement.
At line:4 char:3
+ --data-binary "C:\mypath\profile.json" \
+   ~
Missing expression after unary operator '--'.
At line:4 char:3
+ --data-binary "C:\mypath\profile.json" \
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'data-binary' in expression or statement.
At line:5 char:3
+ --output "C:\profile.csv" \
+   ~
Missing expression after unary operator '--'.
At line:5 char:3
+ --output "C:\profile.csv" \
+   ~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'output' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingExpressionAfterOperator
```

Here's what I've tried:

- putting `myun:mypw` in double quotes
- removing the ampersand after `data-binary`
- Googling "Unexpected token 'header' in expression or statement." But it seems to be a case-by-case basis (which means this is probably one too)
- I understand windows' cURL doesn't like single quotes, but I'm not seeing any here, I'm not sure if there are any other peculiarities along those lines that may be affecting this.

Answer (score 2):

Line breaks in PowerShell are not escaped by a `\` but by the back tick `. So if you want to execute this command in PowerShell either avoid escaping the line breaks at all or use back ticks instead:

```
curl -X POST --user myun:mypw `
--header "Content-Type: application/json" `
--data-binary "@C:\mypath\profile.json" `
"https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/personality-insights/api/v3/profile?version=2016-10-20&consumption_preferences=true&raw_scores=true"
```

Avoiding back ticks would be better though, as they are difficult to read.

Comment: OK, thanks so much. The back ticks worked, but now it says `Invoke-WebRequest : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'X'.` (I also tried `XPOST`)

Comment: Now you have a different problem: In PowerShell `curl` is an alias for `Invoke-WebRequest`, which is a cmdlet with a different syntax than the command you are using. You would be better off with using cmd here instead of PowerShell.

Comment: OK, do I still escape line breaks in cmd?

Comment: Yep, but this time the escape character is the caret ^.